# Awarded only 2 instead of 25 points

Tags: support

Yesterday my reputation points total was 7600. Today I was awarded 25 for answering this: [Is the Javascript API capable of creating Power Query queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70655997/is-the-javascript-api-capable-of-creating-power-query-queries/70672153#70672153), but my total only went up 2 points. How do I fix this?

[image: screenshot of total points and most recently awarded points]

This is what my reputation tab shows:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history) Particularly the section "My reputation went down, but I don't see anything listed!"

Comment: There's a "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom of the page -- you'll need to make sure that's checked.  Note: that checkbox only shows up if you're 1) viewing your own profile, or 2) a CM or Dev staff member

Answer (score 7):

Check out the "[reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6190031/rick-kirkham?tab=reputation)" tab on your user profile to see details about your reputation changes.  In this case, you were awarded +25 for your answer, but a different answer of yours was removed, resulting in a decrease of 23 rep.

[image]

Comment: 4 minutes from post to staff response? Don't let anyone say that The Company doesn't respond to users.

Comment: That's not what I see. There is no "yesterday" listed. I'll add the screenshot to my question.

Comment: You probably didn't check the "show deleted posts" checkbox at the bottom of the page

Comment: Why isn't that checked by default? smh

Comment: @KevinB I thought it was? It's checked for me and I don't recall ever noticing it being there.

Comment: @Nick: Once you set it, it's saved as a user preference, so it'll be remembered for the future.

Comment: @JohnM.Wright Maybe I clicked it a very long time ago then :)