# Reputation gains (+1) due to deletion of posts I have downvoted does not seem to be applied

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, deleted-answers

Some days ago I noticed that, while a post I had downvoted was deleted and the deletion showed up in my reputation tab as +1, the single-point gain was not actually added to my total rep (which ends in 0 for several weeks now, so such changes are easy to spot).

Despite my reasonable certainty that indeed I had a rep ending in 0 before, and it should be ending in 1 afterwards, I dismissed the issue attributing it to a mistaken memory of mine.

But this has just happened again; I had a total rep of 55,380 yesterday, got two upvotes, and a post I had downvoted (on Nov 15) was deleted by a mod:

[image]

but my total rep afterwards is 55,400, instead of 55,401.

Seems to be a bug; any ideas?

Comment: A more... precise place to look would be your reputation audit, rather than the achievement box/reputation at the top.

Comment: @KevinB not sure what a reputation audit is; if you mean the detailed reputation changes (i.e. the reputation tab on the left column of my profile), this is exactly where the screenshot is from - it is **not** from the top right. You could (or should...) have easily  bet that, being here for some time, I would know where to look...

Comment: Yea, that's not what i'm referring to, it's a text output, i forget exactly where it is but can find info on it [here on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history)

Comment: Specifically, https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: @KevinB thanks, but I am afraid this does not answer the question; all reputation changes are supposed to be displayed in the reputation tab - and here they do indeed, but they do not get actually added to the total rep correctly.

Comment: You should still be able to look at the link above for the day where you downvoted it and confirm it's no longer there, counting toward your reputation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You reputation did not change because it was not supposed to. The reputation history doesn't show the full story of what happened with that post:

- The post was deleted from review originally on November 15. You would have gained 1 reputation back at this time when your reputation recalculated.
- The post was undeleted by the author today.
- The post was re-deleted by a moderator a couple hours later.

Normally, at the second event, you would also get another recalculation to take the 1 reputation away again. However, the system never got around to recalculating your account before the post got deleted yet again, which would trigger another reversal.

Since your reputation was still in the state of having received the reputation back from the first deletion, the re-deletion did not actually change your reputation. Technically, it should have done another -1 as well as another +1, resulting in a net 0.

However, to prevent clutter, we only show the *most recent* "removed" event in the reputation history, not every single one that happens over the history of a post.

Your reputation is currently correct.

Comment: Aaaa... so, you mean that I used to have a +1 in Nov 15 (along with the -1 due to the downvote), but this got reversed today that OP undeleted their post (so the +1 is no longer shown in Nov 15), and displaying this +1 was virtually "moved" from Nov 15 to today, when the post was deleted by a mod, right?

Comment: Correct. If you had been recalculated before the second deletion took place, you would have seen your reputation visibly reduce by 1, then increase by 1 again later. But the events occurred faster than the system did the recalcs, making it appear like it just couldn't do math.

Comment: Cool, thanks. So, my previous memory of a similar event (if it is not wrong) may be due to a similar reason, too.

Comment: Probably. For clarification, when removals occur, we don't apply the change to your reputation value. We schedule your account to be recalculated instead. That process completely recalculates your entire history of reputation. It's not possible for it to be "wrong" in that it forgot to add or subtract some amount. It's far more likely to be some other factor that you possibly can't see.