# Stack Overflow removes reputation from accounts without recording it

Tags: support, reputation, notifications

Again and again I had the impression that my reputation goes down instead of up. So yesterday I created a screenshot:

[image]

Today I get the notification that I earned +25 points (and an additional +10 yesterday as the screenshot was taking with +8 yesterday):

[image]

But to my surprise, the total reputation I have now is -20 points lower instead of +35 points as it should be.

[image]

Checking the reputation log does not explain this either:

[image]

So... what is going on here?

Comment: I'm sure there's a good explanation for this. Posts getting deleted, caching, something like that... I strongly doubt this is an actual _bug_.

Comment: [A question that you answered was deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78041432), resulting in removal of the reputation for that answer.

Comment: @RyanM: Thank you for finding that. Where can I find this information? Is there a list of events somewhere?

Comment: BTW: it's not very motivating if hard earned reputation disappears just because the person asking a question realises it was a stupid question later on and deletes it. Just found you can see the reputation being removed in the reputation graph ("Show removed posts" must be enabled) and there is a lot of that going on...

Comment: I guess that is the problem with taking the time to answer beginner questions...

Comment: "I guess that is the problem with taking the time to answer beginner questions..." - no, it's usually the problem with answering *bad* questions that should instead have been closed. There are plenty of beginner questions which are well asked, and deserve answering. *Sometimes* those can still get deleted, but they're *usually* not. Obviously there's a subjective aspect here - but if you only answer questions which you consider to be good questions (ideally deserving of an upvote) then you're less likely to see this problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet "*if you only answer questions which you consider to be good questions (ideally deserving of an upvote) then you're less likely to see this problem*" therein lies the rub, what users consider a good question is also a curve. Ostensibly _no one_ answers questions they think are bad questions. Yet we still see many of them get answers, even sometimes with the answerer saying "this is really off-topic/opinion-based, but..." :-(

Comment: @TehSphinX You have landed on a time-honored item of exceedingly poor design; the powers that be don't think it's "nice" to be notified of reputation loss, so they don't make it show as a notification. Despite reputation _loss_ (at least from other users' votes) being _significantly more important_ to address (if you get an upvote, you probably don't need to make any changes; you're doing well. If you get a downvote, you probably ought to go find that post and improve (or delete) it, for example).

Comment: @TehSphinX *"Where can I find this information? Is there a list of events somewhere?"* Were you not able to see it by following the advice in [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269653/208273)  That sounds like a bug, if so.

Comment: @TylerH: I disagree - I've seen numerous people say "Yes, I agree it's not a good question, but I wanted to help out." You even acknowledged that yourself: "even sometimes with the answerer saying "this is really off-topic/opinion-based, but...". I'm saying that if you find yourself wanting to put that caveat, *don't answer it*.

Comment: @JonSkeet I dunno, that sounds like you agree with me, to me... I have never seen anyone say "this is not a good question" in an answer. Just things *they don't think qualify* as a bad one (which was my point).

Comment: @RyanM Just out of curiosity, what was the status of the question prior to deletion? Closed, score, etc.

Comment: @TylerH: In that case, feel free to re-read my advice as "If you think this would meet one of the close reasons, don't answer it." Distinguishing between saying "this is not a good question" and "this is off-topic/opinion-based" doesn't feel terribly helpful to me.

Comment: Closed, 0 score (+2/-2), @CPlus . 2 answers (+4/-0 and +3/-0).

Comment: @ThomA Deleted by community vote, I assume?

Comment: 1 community, 1 mod vote.

Comment: (There are *also* plenty of *difficult* questions that are asked *incredibly poorly*.)

Comment: @RyanM I eventually found the answer in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653. It is very hidden though and not part of the list of how to loose reputation.

Comment: @RyanM Now that I realize the question was deleted based on mod vote + community vote, I think the problem is even bigger than I originally thought. At least in the Go area there are a few people around that just downvote questions all the time. You open a question like 5min after it was asked and it is already at -2 or more. Of course I can't look into their heads but it feels like a question gets downvoted if there is no straight forward answer and it might take a bit more time than they are willing to invest.

Comment: Taking the question that was deleted here as and example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78041008 The person asking the question obviously had this issue. Given he used generics which are rather new to Go it was easy to not realize that he used the index instead of the value. It even took me a while to realize it and I'm doing Go since beginning of 2016, since ~2 years on Staff Engineer level. So, why close this question?

Comment: IMO questions that receive an answer that is upvoted by 2, 3 or more votes shouldn't be deletable. If the question is really bad it could be improved instead to ask more to the point. In the end, no questions are ever stupid if there is a good answer.

Comment: @TehSphinX the question was closed as a typo, personally though I would have preferred a duplicate closure to a canonical explaining the `range` keyword. Not understanding that the first value produced when iterating over a slice is the index sounds like a common misunderstanding to me. Maybe the users who closed it might have a different perspective.

Comment: for posterity, it's worth mentioning that the second answer on that deleted Q&A was generated with an LLM

Comment: @blackgreen can you provide a link? I don't see a second answer on the question I'm talking about here.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat It is not about closing the question. That is fine. This is about deleting the question.

Comment: @TehSphinX mmh, you can't see it because you are below 10k rep. I thought having an answer there allowed you to see the entire thread even if it's deleted, but that's not the case. Here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj4dy.png

Comment: @TehSphinX it was probably deleted because it was closed as a typo. I generally agree that typo questions aren't very useful and should be deleted.