# Mod request to undo targeted downvotes

Tags: support, downvotes, serial-voting

I recently saw three downvotes on my [three most downvoted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269037/dan-dascalescu?tab=questions&sort=votes&page=2), all occurring within one minute. I have 10k+ rep, so I don't care about minus 6. The behavior itself though reeks of vandalism.

[image]

I flagged one of the question asking for moderator attention. The response was:

> Unfortunately, I don't see enough of a pattern to solidly indicate targeted voting here.

How can anyone reasonably believe this was NOT a targeted downvoter at work? They looked for my most downvoted questions using the *sort by votes* feature, then downvoted each of them. The questions are on very different tags - Meteor, Angular and Excel VBA. It is humanly impossible to read them within a minute and judge them as "bad". This was clearly a malicious act.

The chances of random different users with expertise in Meteor, Angular and Excel VBA users looking within a minute at my most downvoted questions are so astronomically low as to not even merit discussion.

Comment: Seriously, you realize that if we answer this question, we give a lot of useful information to people who may want to circumvent the serial voting detection routine, right?

Comment: [Please check out this FAQ post on serial voting.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes) To sum it up: If the system detects serial downvoting, it will be reversed within 24 hours. For all you know, it could have been three different users that just so happened to vote down on three of your posts at the same time.

Comment: 3 votes just isn't enough to prove targeting. It could all be the same user who is annoyed at you, but you can't prove it (neither can the mod who handled the flag).

Comment: Um. Let's not be facetious here. It was clearly someone who was pissed at me, looked for my "worst" questions, and downvoted each again.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Or, if they were your worst questions, it could have been three different users who found your worst questions through search and downvoted them because they felt it was deserved. _You have no way of knowing who downvoted any of your posts. That information is kept anonymous for a reason._ Please do not make assumptions when there is no possible way for you to know. Not even mods can see who voted for a post. As it stands, if the system counts it as serial downvoting, it will be reversed. If not, it very well could have been three different users, it could not, _you don't know._

Comment: @Dan, I don't think we're being facetious here. If you want an anecdote, I will cite my own case -- I also *think* I may have been targeted by revenge downvotes, and also cannot prove it, but... I only have one question, so it cannot possibly trigger any kind of threshold. I've seen first-hand serial downvoting being reversed on my answers, but... not ever on my question. But as others have said, that question may be bad from the get-go, and I cannot possibly know the difference between revenge downvotes and people hinting at me to improve it. So goes life.

Comment: For example, three of my questions literally just got downvoted. I'm at very low rep with few posts, so that's a nice setback and lead toward a possible ban. Sure, I could assume it was you, @DanDascalescu, but I have no proof. For all I know, Frederic went to check my profile and found a question wanting, and maybe Martijn did the same for another question. It's really nothing to get worked up over. If the questions are good and on-topic, chances are they gain upvotes to outweigh those. (Though if I don't want those three deleted, I'd better go improve them so they do draw upvotes...)

Comment: This has happened to me several times, usually after a conflict with a user. There's nothing to be done but to shrug it off

Comment: "Unfortunately, I don't see enough of a pattern to solidly indicate targeted voting here." the mod's toolset uses an algorithm to determine if downvoting reaches a "serial" level and, only after, then reveals the user doing it.  The mod is saying the tools aren't telling him this is serial downvoting.  There isn't anything he can do about it if the tools won't cooperate.

Comment: **Without** looking at your answers, when coming across a really wild answer that proposes something counterproductive or irresponsible (asker or others could waste a lot of time trying to make it work, or end up with a dangerous result), it can be quite tempting to wonder if that poster has other similarly poor answers, go and check, and act appropriately if such are found.  Algorithmically that's not easy to distinguish from revenge; but if those are indeed bad answers, then there's nothing wrong with downvoting them.

Comment: And if there is something that you now recognize as arguably bad about some of your answers, you might consider editing them to improve that, strikeout the bad parts, etc.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: what was downvoted were my [most downvoted *questions*](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1269037/dan-dascalescu?tab=questions&sort=votes&page=2). It is humanly impossible to read through those three questions within a minute, judge them as "bad", and downvote them. They are also in vastly different tags: Angular, Meteor and Excel VBA. Extremely few people know all three.

Comment: @ChrisStratton My understanding based on previous discussions is that it's considered wrong to go to somebody's profile, start looking through their answers, and start voting on them. Even if your votes are based on the merits of the posts, it would still be considered serial voting.

Comment: Hopefully not.  Going from suspicions raised by one or two odd posts through someone's profile to the rest of their posts is a key part of figuring out if they are pattern spamming, repeating the same question, generally misunderstanding how the site works, etc.  In not all of those cases are downvotes the best result, however.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: The inaction on this request now serves as a perfect proof of how vandalism under a certain threshold will go unpunished.

Comment: @Dan, what do you mean by *inaction*? You received two perfectly good answers.

Comment: @Frédéric, those answers were basically "no, because bureaucracy".

Comment: @Dan, you're right. I probably should have posted an answer outright screaming **No, -6 reputation to one user is not worth revolutionizing the system.** That's not bureaucracy, that's only you (and I, and all the others) not being beautiful, unique snowflakes.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi same thing just happened to me too, and I bet it happened to others as well. And for two of the three questions that were downvoted -this was the only downvote, check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577079/why-declare-a-copy-of-a-private-field-as-final and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870489/regex-to-match-a-word-with-unique-non-repeating-characters. So it's not necessarily some of the "most downvoted questions" but it *could* be plain malicious behavior.

Answer (score 11):

> The chances of random different users doing the same thing within a minute are so astronomically low as to not even merit discussion.

That's not really true. The odds of that happening to one specific (selected beforehand) user are astronomically low, but there are millions of users on Stack Overflow. The odds of it happening to *someone* are not as low.  In light of that, we can't set the threshold so low that it's constantly setting off false positives.

Having said that, I do agree with you that this looks at least a little suspicious. Looking through your voting history though, I can't see enough to actually *do anything* about it. I can't see who cast those three specific votes among all of the votes you've received, so I really can't solidly (with 100% certainty) say that it was targeted voting by one user, even if we agree that it *probably* was. If it was, then you can rest assured this won't be the last time. The user will most likely repeat this behavior, either against you or someone else. Let us know if it keeps happening, and we'll be happy to take action once a stronger pattern does emerge.

Comment: Bill, this question makes me wonder another question. If you get serial downvoted to the point the system recognizes it, then delete one post that, if not downvoted, wouldn't trigger the reversal system, would the system still reverse votes? If you happen to know, that is, and just out of curiosity. If you don't know, do you think that'd be a meta question worth raising, or one unlikely to receive an answer?

Comment: @Kendra I don't know. You'd have to delete posts before the system detects the downvoting pattern, as I'm pretty sure it reverses the votes as soon as it detects them. My guess is that it would ignore votes on posts that you deleted, but that's 100% speculation based on how I would implement it, not based on anything I've seen.

Comment: Well, I know from the FAQ that the script runs once a day. It was just a curiosity thing because, strangely enough, after commenting here I got downvoted. (I really don't care if it was serial or not, looking at those questions they were all three pretty bad and needed deleted or edited.) I deleted one of the questions, and that made me wonder about that. (Not in my case, I really doubt those three count for serial downvoting to begin with and really it's only 6 rep, four after that delete.)

Comment: In addition, it should be pointed out that if the serial voting script doesn't catch a series of targeted votes, the only way to deal with those is to call in an SE employee. There are fewer of those than moderators, and they tend to be a little more busy, so if they're going to go to the trouble of checking and invalidating votes in the database, it has to be for a serious problem. Two or three votes generally isn't, so this would usually need to develop into a more troublesome series of votes before it would be worth bothering one of them.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, the threshold is not made public, very much on purpose. We don't want malicious serial voters tune their voting to avoid detection.

Moreover, there is more to serial voting detection than just a simple minimal-number-of-posts-voted-on. Previous voting behaviour between users [appears to play a role](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting/144478#144478), as well as other factors.

Last but not least, your down votes could have come from two or three separate users, and the closeness of the votes is just a coincidence.

Comment: You're just playing devil's advocate. I've been on SO for five years, and this has never happened. The odds of three different users looking at my worst questions *within a minute* and downvoting each of them are just ridiculously low.

Comment: @DanDascalescu: But far from impossible. If someone mentioned your account in a chat room you could easily have several people look at your account at the same time.

Comment: @DanDascalescu With a couple million users on SO, no, probably not. And as to your newest edit, mods can't undo downvotes. Only community leaders can, and that's only if they find very good reason to. (I could be wrong about that, but looking at Chris' answer on the FAQ I linked to leads me to believe this is correct.)

Comment: @DanDascalescu As you say; you've been here five years. Lots of things can happen. We have seen things much more 'damning' than this turn out to be bona fide, completely, utterly innocent. That said; give things some time... either the pattern will grow, or you'll just have a tiny handful of stray DV's... I have *scores* of these, myself ;)

Comment: Then we have a coordinated serial downvoting attack. Does that make it more legit? Not that I care about -6 repo when I'm over 10k; it's just disappointing to see injustice ignored.

Comment: @DanDascalescu: 3 votes is hardly an attack. And if 3 users looking at 3 different questions independently decide to downvote there is nothing malicious going on either.

Comment: @DanDascalescu This is, as you say, the first time you've seen this happen. "injustice" seems a bit hyperbolic to describe this. And as far as us ignoring this... if only you knew..

Comment: @DanDascalescu Or, instead of coordinated serial downvoting, perhaps one of your posts was being praised and a few people went to look at others and judge accordingly. You're assuming the worst of people here.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I have no idea what you are talking about! ;)

Comment: Nor do I, @AndrewBarber; I have no comment in this thread!

Comment: `"...and the closeness of the votes is just a coincidence."` -- While I agree that three down-votes are nothing to get all concerned about, I have to wonder that with votes coming at less than one minute apart for questions that are separated in time by 7 months, I think we know that the odds of @DanDascalescu's down-votes being a coincidence are astronomically small. We're seriously talking 1 in 10,000 type odds.

Comment: @Kendra: I've updated my OP to mention that the questions were on vastly different tags. Nobody can read, comprehend, navigate and judge them as "bad" within one minute.

Comment: I agree with @HovercraftFullOfEels, getting 3 downvotes in one minute for questions/answers that were published months away is obviously another user trolling you. I'm not sure why such high rep users such as Martijn,  Andrew Barber, Kendra and others burry their heads in the sand and assume this is actually "normal" behavior: the number of users in SO has nothing to do with it, and if you want to be honest with yourself you should also take into consideration the number of questions and answers in SO, the time they were published to see what are the chances of something like this to happen...

Comment: @alfasin: no-one is burying any heads, alfasin. I'm merely enumerating other possibilities. SO is *big enough* that you can't rule out the possibility,

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: this is a very narrow window on the site; there were probably hundreds of downvotes across many different posts at that moment, but the reputation view for one user won't show anything but the votes that arrived on their own posts.. These three had this one author in common, but we can't know for sure if they also have the voter in common.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: gosh I had completely forgotten about this 2.5 yr old comment. I have to wonder what stimulated alfasin to join in this old discussion?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels the fact that the same happened to me today. I was searching meta to see if there was a question on the topic. The extreme example is a question I asked long time ago and which had 16 upvotes with no downvotes at all until I received this "downvote wave".

Comment: @alfasin: if you received a "down-vote wave" of sufficient size, the site's software should identify this and reverse it, although this often takes a day or three to happen.

Comment: I understand that it might be a stretch to call 3 simultaneous downvotes "a wave" but the fact that these posts are old makes it weird: how come users dag so far in history and accidently ran into these three posts, and downvoted all of them at the same time, left no comment in all cases. And yes, when a downvoted question is one that had only upvotes in the past, and many of them - makes it even more suspicious.

Comment: I just got downvoted in 4 different questions of different subjects at the same minute like OP. I came here looking for some possible action to take but it appears there's no one to report. This makes me concerned.