# Can we flag a specific user?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, moderation

I think it would be a great option to be able to flag a specific user for misbehavior, such as the potential of downvoting another user just to lower their reputation. Granted it might be difficult to determine the user doing this, but in a stream of negative comments, it is sometimes obvious who is doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find one of their posts, cast a custom moderator flag on it, and explain the problem.

Comment: I think this is the best option.  I wouldn't think that needing to flag a user would be a typical action.  Besides, this kind of flag would probably need a bunch of explanation and moderator attention anyway, so a custom flag seems to be the logical choice.

Answer (score 2):

First, [targeted downvotes are usually handled automatically by the system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes).

If there's a larger problem, or the system hasn't taken care of these after a day or so, you can flag one of the posts in question or an arbitrary one by that user.

I would suggest avoiding accusations in comments or other posts, because you'd be surprised at how often people are wrong about who is downvoting their posts. Leave it to a private flag for us to handle behind the scenes.

In this case, I'd already been cleaning up the comments on that post and had noticed the voting. I've left the user responsible a polite warning about this, and the system should do the rest later today or tomorrow.

Comment: Great, thank you for this response. This is good to know that the system works this way!