# Channel to contact admin or moderator

Tags: support

What is the channel to contact with administrator or moderator of this site to report a situation with an account?

Comment: What kind of situation?  Custom flags usually work (explained).

Comment: A couple a days ago a member was navigating old question/answer from me downvoting some of them.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes

Comment: So not about this cough [*rollback war*](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29898464/revisions) cough?

Comment: @Jongware, Im not talking about it.

Comment: @codeMagic, obviously that didn't work

Comment: @E-Bat just giving you what I could with the little bit of information you posted. Anyway, I guess you are saying it's been more than 24 hours, did you see [the related meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) in that link?

Comment: The pattern was not of a serial, a user angry with me take 2 or 3 old question and downvote it, is that an allowed behavior?

Comment: I really want to understand why you downvote when I want to report a harm to my account

Comment: I don't know why there are so many downvotes, but the answer is pretty apparent to experienced users (flag, or even the "contact us" link), so this questions doesn't show a lot of research.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I can only assume the dvs may be because there wasn't much of an explanation in your post as to *why* you wanted to contact someone. Depending on the reason, it can change the answer of who and how. Also know that downvotes here don't hurt you.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, I really do not use very hard this site, I didnt even realized of those links. Your comment is the answer for this question. I dont know why many often people are so eager to downvote than to help.

Comment: @E-Bat Presumably you read the privilege you got at 5 rep to flag posts, so there's that. Like I said, its not -13 score bad though.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, yes I'm aware of that regard to posts, but it is not obvious how to flag a malicious downvote. It could be a good feature.

Comment: And that one is covered the FAQ: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes pinned to the right side of the main page of meta. For that exact feature, the guidance is plentiful here.

Answer (score 14):

It depends on what kind of issue you want to report.

If you have an issue with another user, you can pick one of their comments or posts and flag that with the *in need of moderator intervention* option. Explain in that flag what your issue is.

You can also use the *contact us* link in the footer of every page.

Comment: A couple a days ago a member was navigating old question/answer from me downvoting some of them.

Comment: @E-Bat: You already reported this in another message, I see. We'll probably respond to that when we have investigated properly.

Comment: Ok, I'll wait, so I came here looking for help and was punished with (so far ) 11 downvotes, it sounds fair.

Comment: @E-Bat don't be churlish; this information was **very** available beforehand (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators), and it looks like you've already had the serial voting reversed.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, investigate and you will see what i'm saying, the beginner of that situation nothing happens to him ok, so i'm churlish to who was  doing the same with me.

Comment: None of your questions seem to have as many as 11 down votes, @E-Bat

Comment: @TZHX: they are talking about this question.

Comment: @E-Bat assuming I've understood *"the beginner of that situation nothing happens to him ok"* correctly, as *"whoever downvoted me wasn't punished"*, I suggest you read the last two paragraphs of http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/248731.

Comment: So what about my complaint, no investigation done yet?

Comment: @E-Bat: things take time, have a little patience. Some things have to be delegated to employees, which means we have to wait.