# User downvoting a question because I didn't accept their answer?

Tags: discussion

In a recent question I asked, ([scrollHeight is more than clientHeight, even without scrolling content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642367/scrollheight-is-more-than-clientheight-even-without-scrolling-content)), two answers were given, one explaining what was happening but not explaining how to fix it clearly, while the other one explained how to fix my issue.

When I accepted the latter, it appears the poster of the former answer downvoted my question. I came to this conclusion by the comment they made on the accepted answer.

This could have been because I didn't specifically ask how to fix the problem even though that is what I was expecting. If the case is that the user who posted the first answer **did** downvote my question, is that right for them to do that?

If it is right of them to do that, then if I had have asked how to fix the problem in the question would it still be right of them to downvote my question just because I did not accept their answer?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something that user added the comment to get clarification before deciding to have a go at an answer. I see no reason to think they downvoted it.

Comment: No, I was referring to their comment on the accepted answer. "I came to this conclusion by the comment they made on the **accepted answer**."
Also the downvote happened at roughly the same time as the comment.

Comment: From what I can see the person who provided the other answer didn't leave a comment on the accepted answer, only your question.

Comment: I cant see a comment on the answer from Schomz.  I doubt a 22k user would feel so deprived of 15 pts that they would resort to a revenge DV.  Regardless, there are 2 DVs all told.  They are anon so you cant really know for certain who the voters are.

Comment: It seems their comment has been deleted, and either the downvote was revoked by the user or someone else upvoted it, but at the time of asking the question, there was a comment from Schomz on the accepted answer.

Comment: As of now, there are 2 upvotes and 2 downvotes on your question.  That might be the meta effect though.

Comment: Votes happening seemingly instantaneously happens often enough that "How/Why did people vote before reading my question?" is a frequent question. The assumption that if a comment and vote happen at the same time then the commentor was the one who voted is nowhere near reasonable. Seeing the vote count change while I type a comment *is the norm*.

Comment: If they did think it wasn't clear that you wanted a fix, it was probably less to do with you not explicitly asking for one and more that you said this: "This isn't a problem unless it is a bug and is fixed in the future." - This statement sounds like you're saying you're not looking for a fix unless the behavior is a bug.

Answer (score 4):

> This could have been because I didn't specifically ask how to fix the
>   problem even though that is what I was expecting.

That sounds like your question is unclear, at least slightly.  And an unclear post is one of the main reason people downvote posts.  It's even in the tooltip for the downvote arrow.

Regardless, people are (mostly) free to vote however they want so long as it isn't gaming the system with serial voting.  More importantly, there's no way of knowing for sure who or why your question was downvoted.  Even if the downvote was cast for the reason you suspect, it's petty, not forbidden.  Only if you suspect serial voting, is it really an issue.  If so, read this [meta post on how to handle suspected serial voting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes).