# Could / should any action be taken against repetitive downvotes?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, downvote-reason

Recently I received a downvote on a number of my questions in a single minute. It's hard to assume that those came from different users, especially given that those questions are not recent at all. Some a few months old, some years old, none active recently.

Apparently someone disliked some actions of mine which is strange because I'm never rude/impolite/etc.

It's not at all about reputation loss, but the principle. Up/downvotes should not be personal. Going through someone's questions and downvoting them is an abuse of the voting system.

This could be prevented with a simple constraint, e.g. limit the number of downvotes by the same user on the same user's posts in a given timeframe.

Comment: See [What can I do about getting a sudden flood of revenge downvotes?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes)

Comment: you're right no one SHOULD have gone through your profile to downvote stuff... IF someone did it, then it will be reverted

Comment: As pointed out in the above-linked post, these should be invalidated by the system later before tomorrow. I've gone ahead and warned the user responsible to make sure they understand that this isn't proper behavior.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that there's already a system watching out for such anomalies. I don't really understand the downvotes on this question though. I saw other posts on Meta marked as duplicate and still not downvoted. Was it a mistake to ask this?

Comment: @marekful I guess the lack of research is what people don't like....

Comment: Happens to everyone, just live with it. Unless it happens day after day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is someone downvoting all of your questions there is a script that is run daily to check for serial voting and it will revert any serial voting that it detects.