# Is it allowed to continually up vote someone's answers and questions?

Tags: support, upvotes, serial-voting, rules

I have been noticing random upvotes on all my questions and answers (a large increase in them on all my questions and answers, most of them being older posts).

While I should be happy, I guess, I am afraid that I will get banned or penalized for this. Is there a penalty to the receiver? What can I do to stop this?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me

Comment: Yeah, we'll buy that.  You'll find out tomorrow.

Comment: Good news, you don't need to worry about those votes anymore.

Answer (score 10):

> I guess, I am afraid that I will get banned or penalized for this. Is there a penalty to the receiver?

No, there's no penalty. Don't worry, you won't get penalized or banned if that happens to you, unless there's proof that you did these votes from a sockpuppet, or you've been detected as a member of a voting ring.

The votes usually will be reverted the same way as it's [explained here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes) for a flood of downvotes.

You don't need to take any action.

Also see this [SE Meta Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) as mentioned by [@Robert Longson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318323/is-it-allowed-to-continually-up-vote-someones-answers-and-questions#comment317744_318323).