# Have I been serial down-voted?

Tags: support, serial-voting

I checked my reputation tab a bit ago, and noticed something a bit odd (partial list in screenshot, the full list is much longer).

Did someone do this? Or is the system acting strangely?

[image: Screenshot of Serial Downvote]

Comment: Wait till UTC 03:00 (http://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)

Comment: This just looks like a bug, some of these answers/questions have been out there for years. Could it be a bug, or is it only possible for someone to actually click the vote button?

Comment: If somebody gets pissed off at you for some reason then it is always best that he gets *really* mad and only stops when his index finger runs out.

Comment: Someone just loved to click that button. If you go to sleep now and wake up in like 10 hours, everything will be reversed :)

Comment: @HansPassant I guess it's a compliment if a person did it :) Probably was a robot tho. There are like 50 of them.  I would feel honored that someone would waste all that time on me.

Comment: The only surprising thing here is that it took you this long to get your first serial downvote ;-) People can get angry at you for the silliest reasons (strangely it always seems to happen to me when I'm actually being polite and patient, never in one of my more sarcastic and snarky moods).

Comment: @theMayer Whatever the case, the serial downvoting reversal script will catch and annihilate it.

Comment: My cover has been blown! :^)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you were serial downvoted.  There is a system in place to catch this behavior which runs daily, but if you check your reputation tab you'll notice that it's already been reversed.

## Related reading:

- [What can I do about getting a sudden flood of revenge downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes)

Answer (score 4):

It looks very much like a serial downvoting applied from a single user within two minutes.

Don't worry, such voting patterns will be recognized by the engine automatically and reversed within 24 hours. Usually you don't need to take any action about this yourself.