# Why did all my questions get down voted by Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, serial-voting

I was just going through my profile and I discovered that I had lost some points when I checked my profile I found out that I was down-voted on a lot of my questions for no apparent reason what did I do wrong?

I've read other meta posts where other users lost points for deleting their upvoted questions but I didn't delete any of my questions.

[image: Screen shot of the downvotes]

Comment: The answer to your question is over in [this FAQ post.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes) It looks like serial downvoting, and should be reversed when the script runs.

Comment: You were targeted by another person with a series of downvotes because they were upset with you for some trivial reason. I gave them a warning, and these votes should be invalidated by the system sometime before the end of tomorrow. Sorry you had to encounter that, but it's only temporary.