# Is there a way to understand downvoting?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes, downvote-reason

Is there a way to understand downvoting?

I have a question opened about a year ago. This question (for some reason that I don't really understand) got downvote a few minutes ago.

To tell the truth - it looks like someone just trying to harm my reputation (I can't really think about other reason, as this question already got an upvote in the past).

I already checked multiple questions and answers here regarding this.
Any comment will be appreciated.

Comment: Hardly think a single downvote (which would be 0.01% of your reputation) is an attempt to harm your reputation.  Changes are more likely that someone just stumbled upon your question and felt it wasn't useful or wasn't clear. or didn't show research effort (that is what the tooltip on the downvote button says)

Comment: And the meta affect piles in ...

Comment: @DavidPostill well positive meta effect in my case - went to one of the OP's posts - it gave me some nice insight for what I am doing, so an upvote.

Comment: [Tim lost his keys yet again?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/165773)

Comment: lol. Everyone gets the occasional random downvote.

Answer (score 9):

> Is there a way to understand downvoting?

No, there is no way. There's a [guideline](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question) for downvoting but I doubt more than 10% of the privileged users have read it. Everybody is free to downvote on posts as he/she wants, except when [*repeatedly*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes) targeting a user. A single downvote isn't going to hurt in the long run.