# Timeline to address custom moderator flags

Tags: discussion

<sub>**Disclaimer**: While this question calls out a specific instance of an issue as an example, please do not attempt in any way to get involved in this specific issue if you are not a moderator. This question is *specifically* to get a better understanding around custom moderator flagging.</sub>

---

I recently acquired a [fan](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes#comment110227_252270) who thinks it's appropriate to serial downvote me repeatedly. This has happened four times in the last week.

Fortunately the system has been automatically reverting the votes, however more recently they've become more persistent by leaving comments that toe the line of being acceptable.

I flagged the issue after the *second* time I was serially downvoted, but as that was a week ago and it's happened twice more since then I'm not really sure what I can do to address this issue in a timely fashion.

I don't want to be pushy, but I would like a better understanding of what sort of timeline I should expect for these sorts of issues.

Is a week enough time to address the issue? Is a month?

Is it appropriate to raise such issues as questions on meta?

Is there a better channel that avoids the meta effect?

Comment: No, you shouldn't be bringing this up on meta.  This is something that's between you and the mods, not for other community members to be involved in.

Comment: Sometimes it takes a bit of time for the mods to get to custom flags, but be certain that if you have someone targeting you it will be handled when the mods get to your flag.

Comment: Thanks for not calling out the user here.  There is nothing that non moderators can do so really all you can do is use moderator flags.  There is the contact us page but I'm not sure if that will help it go any faster.

Comment: @bluefeet, sure but is there any data for average turn-around on flags? It's hard to be patient when the system doesn't have any feedback. If I had information on how long say 95% of flags sit in the queue, then I would know when it's appropriate to reach out, rather than wondering if I should wait another week or whether I should just keep ignoring things for another six months.

Comment: @NathanOliver, good point, I'm going to add a note about that to the question to make that more clear.

Comment: @zzzzBov Custom flags are much more difficult to handle, thus they take significantly longer to process. I don't have numbers offhand, I'd have to go poking in the database.

Comment: Maybe I should add a feature request to be able to have the flag queue include feedback along the lines of "95% of flags resolved in under X days" or something like that based on the last month or six of flagging data.

Comment: @zzzzBov - Moderators have a limited dashboard for this. It currently reports that in the last 30 days we've handled 67590 flags with an average duration before handling of 9 hours, 46 minutes. Custom flag handling time can vary wildly when we have a lot of flags in the queue, because a high-urgency flag can get buried in "plz anzer thiz" or "this answer is wrong" noise flags. We unfortunately don't have a way of sorting these right now, so it's hard to triage when the queue reaches a certain size.

Comment: @BradLarson, how are the flags sorted? fifo? priority based on metrics? magic?

Comment: @zzzzBov - Within a category of flag: first by number of flags on a specific post, then simply by time submitted. That's fine for standard flag categories, but the custom flags are so varied that it breaks down. I had a filter script for searching these with common terms, but that broke in a recent build. We've talked with SE staff for a while about the kind of filtering options to apply here so that flags like yours would be more visible.

Comment: @zzzzBov Custom flags, from personal experience, take around 2 weeks +/- about a week. So the time it takes that your flag gets handled can really vary, but very roughly I would say that it takes about 2 weeks for a custom flag.

Comment: So that works out, on average, to a little over 100 flags per mod per day, that's some workload! I wonder (because there's always one) who is that one mod who does several hundred every day? :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, you never want to call out specific users on Meta. If you believe you are being targeted by someone, then I'd recommend flagging for moderator attention using a custom 'other' flag.

Unfortunately, the moderator flag queue tends to be a bit large on Stack Overflow, so it may take a bit of time for them to process the flags. The flag will be handled eventually, and if there is any indication that you have been targeted it will be taken care of by the moderation team.

By the way, [we are currently holding an election for more mods](https://stackoverflow.com/election/9), if you're keen on helping out the current team, then nominate yourself.

Comment: `First, you never want to call out specific users on Meta.` actually, you *do*, to provide much-needed spectacle and entertainment for all of us! How can you go around give such advice!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I would make a *terrible* moderator.

Comment: Terrible is fine @zzzzBov we also need a mod that we can call out on meta constantly ...