# How to deal with "difficult"/"brazen" users?

Tags: discussion, users

A few weeks, or even months, ago, I had to quickly finish a work sample to secure my first position as a junior software engineer.

The work sample included developing an application, for a "new" platform, which barely had English documentation or samples and I had no experience in*. I was under time pressure and was searching for an answer for my problems (2 in total), since they were total deal breakers in development.

To make it clear: those questions were related to tasks, which actually had good tutorials on how to achieve these tasks. The problem was, however, even if the same exact steps were taken (i.e. at some point trying to run the sample), the application wouldn't behave as expected and as described in the documentation.

I made it clear in the question and comments, that I already did exactly like in the tutorial.

On my questions, there was this particular user, who brazenly copy'n'pasted the tutorials (even the pictures and typos), asked me to follow the steps and posted this as an answer.

In the comments, I stated out that I already tried the exact same steps, **before** I actually filled the questions. However, he replied always with the same thing: "Follow the steps AGAIN" or "Start from the given official template AGAIN".

At some point, I figured out the solutions on my own and posted them as an accepted answer. He "revenge" down-voted me on most of my posts. After that, I lost my temper and gave him my opinion, which, what I am glad about, got removed by the moderators.

Apparently, the user made a strategy out of this, since most of his answers are similar to those I encountered before, and I am afraid** to deal with him on other questions related to the same platform.

**How do I deal with such brazen users in future?**

---

*The company would require me to dip into new and undocumented technology on a regular basis.

**I have a lot of downvotes on low-quality questions, answers and comments back from a time, when I was 13 or 14 and wasn't really mature. Basically, every down vote can get me question banned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do about getting a sudden flood of revenge downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes)

Comment: The question is somewhat related, I agree. I am not asking because of the downvotes; i am asking on how to deal in general with such users.

But I am afraid, that my englisch skills are too limited to express my point preciscely.

Comment: How do you know that he revenge downvoted you?

Comment: Forget the downvoting. Julien should probably just remove the downvoting as it detracts from the point. The problematic behavior here is the alleged rudeness. That is a problem, a flaggable one at that. Ultimately this depends on the situation of couse, though I do not recommend linking to the specific post as that would invoke the meta effect, and may be seen as an attempt to publicly shame the user which is not OK. If you see rude behavior, flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: I agree with Tiny Giant in the sense that such a person should be flagged. After flagging continue to ignore the messages of the user

Comment: If the user regularly copy-pastes manuals, that is plagiarism. Plagiarism is reason for a custom moderator flag. When flagging for plagiarism, it's best if you can show where it is copy-pasted from.

Comment: "*He "revenge" down-voted me **on most of my posts.***" I can't help but to check your public reputation history and I only saw 3 downvotes recently: 2 on your latest question, and 1 on your latest self-answer. Either you over-exaggerated, or the revenge downvoting has been reversed.

Comment: ... but to directly answer your question (ignoring all other issues): keep calm and move on.

Answer (score 14):

If you see someone copying and pasting text without proper attribution, flag it and let us know. This is considered plagiarism, and you'll notice we've now removed many of the answers that were posted by this user.

Likewise, if someone is being rude and abusive in comments, be sure to flag those or flag the post they're on with a description of the problem. We're glad to look into that and clean up problematic comments. We will also issue warnings as appropriate to try and steer people away from this behavior so that others don't experience it in the future.

Comment: Boilerplate answers to poorly documented questions rubs me the wrong way on meta as it does on SO.  [This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45705769/17034) behaved as well as anybody could expect when essential info is revealed in comments instead of the question.  Top answerer in the tag as well.  Please protect our valuable contributors as well as our inept questioners.  Heck, more.

Comment: @HansPassant One of that user's (now deleted) recent answers was a copy-paste of the official documentation - without attribution.