# How to end this "this isn't a duplicate" situation with the OP?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I hammered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47839724/run-an-executable-via-a-python-script-and-hide-cmd-window) with a very good target, plus I personally tested the accepted answer and it works fine.

Now the OP is kind of mad at me, because the answer doesn't work for him that's why he asked another question (but the *same* question).

I stated that the OP issue is different, but he doesn't or is unable to explain how it's different, so we couldn't answer even if we wanted to.

So I'm here with the OP in comments trying to explain how the site works (the user has 1.8k rep and *should* know how it works, but...), the question closed, and no other user to back me up (there's no real reason to flag this for moderation either).

How to end this without:

- getting revenge downvotes?
- without reopening (I definitely won't reopen until I know why the issue is different)?
- without letting a disappointed user post a new same question in a few days?

Comment: move on and let someone else handle it

Comment: @Jean That's most probably a duplicate question here ;-) You didn't mention being banned because of too many _"revenge flags"_ being raised at your account BTW.

Comment: @user0042 hey, that's _not_ a duplicate :) (more seriously, I did a bit of googling before posting, but I could have missed something, meta questions are more difficult to find than SO questions)

Comment: and I'm not too scared of being banned :)

Comment: "How to end this without getting revenge downvotes?" Don't mind about them, [the system will reverse them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252271/3151675).

Comment: @the4kman not if they're subtle. You have to flag them in that case.

Comment: OR... you can do what you just did and within 48 hours watch the original question 404 away into oblivion! "Page Not Found
This question was voluntarily removed by its author." Seriously though, that question/answer could have helped someone else.

Comment: @LarryB you cannot see it because you need more rep, but this was an exact duplicate. The author of the post deleted it only to repost a more accurate version of his question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47840633/hide-console-window-by-an-exe-file-executed-by-a-py-script. No answer so far...

Comment: While the update is nice - it's not relevant to the original question and answers. There's no need to draw attention to things further here. Thanks.

Comment: @JonClements no problem. Note that the vote on the new OP question is mine, so I didn't want bad things to happen to him.

Comment: I did comment on the original and they seemed to have made a more specific question that wasn't a (obvious) dupe and was happy to leave it at that. Just no need to extend this post any further regarding your initial concern is all.

Comment: If I see a poster claiming "this is not a duplicate" without explanation, I down vote, ignore their protestations, and vote to close.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> How to end this without getting revenge downvotes

I personally never consider this when deciding what to do, and get very few revenge downvotes, surprisingly few in fact.  I strongly encourage you to not consider this in the slightest when determining what to do.

> without reopening

Don't click the reopen button

> without letting a disappointed user post a new same question in a few days

Without becoming a mod there's nothing you can do here; the best you can do is close the question again if you notice them re-posting it.

---

At this point you've already done what you can.  You've pointed them to the duplicate, you've explained that if they are having a problem with the answers provided there that they need to explain what those problems are, which would then differentiate the question enough to get it reopened.  At this point it's on them.  There's nothing more for you to do until they're able to clarify their question.

Answer (score 27):

Ultimately that question is not a duplicate, but rather a debugging question concerning the implementation of the solution proposed at the duplicate. I admit, this is hidden very, very, very well, but nonetheless.

Now that doesn't let the question off the hook either. This debugging question is missing an MCVE, a clear problem statement, steps to reproduce, and probably a few other things I'm forgetting to mention.

What would have probably helped in this case, and cases like this, would be to tell the user that they should:

- Start from a clean installation, whether that be in a virtual machine or whatever that may mean in the given context,
- Reduce the code to just what is needed to reproduce the issue, and
- Detail all steps to necessary to reproduce the issue from start to finish.

Telling a user to "prove it" without telling them *how* to do that leaves them confused and frustrated. The intention is in the right place, you want them to identify the source of their issue and ask how to fix it; but the explanation of  how to go about doing that is necessary as well.

Communication on the internet is hard sometimes, and that in and of itself can be frustrating and confusing, so if we could all put a bit more effort into articulating what we want, we might just get it a bit more often.