# Got 100 reputation in 1 minute. Should I be worried?

Tags: support, reputation, serial-voting

Today I got 100 reputation. Looking at the history, it's 10 reputation on eight answers I made, along with 5 reputation on four questions.

It looks very odd, almost like one person trying to award me for something. I don't really care about the score.

I assume this will correct itself? Or will it have an impact on my account?

Comment: If it’s indeed one person or a tight knit group of people, it’ll be reversed automatically in a day or two. This will have no impact on your account other than removing those points. You have done nothing wrong (unless you’re managing a sock farm, which you’re likely not doing if you asked this question :). It could also be completely valid and natural, several people found your posts helpful around the same time, in which case you’ll keep the rep.

Comment: Yup, likely serial voting, will probably get reverted. If it doesn't get reverted in a couple of days, you should modflag one of your questions or answers, explain the suspicious voting activity, and ask a mod to investigate. Some voting rings vote on random accounts to make their behavior seem less suspicious, but usually not this often.

Comment: See the MSE post [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: You should add that they're votes on *different answers*. It's perfectly normal for you to get many votes on a popular post.

Comment: (usually because of HNQ. Some people don't like it because it promotes controversial not-very-good question etc., but that's a differnet topic)

Comment: Related [What can I do about getting a sudden flood of revenge downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes)

Comment: Does look odd..

Comment: 100 points spread over a day wouldn't be that dramatic, so I changed the title to emphasize the actual timestamps.

Comment: 100 points over a day _is_ dramatic. It's just not enough :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The timestamps on your votes look a lot like the conditions described in this article from the help centre:

> When a single user continually votes (up or down) on many of your posts within a short period of time, the system considers these votes to be invalid and removes them. This could happen for a variety of reasons, ***such as a user finding a user's great answer and visiting all of their posts to upvote them***... No matter the cause, this sort of systematic targeted voting is not considered normal behavior and the system will not allow it.

If you receive a reputation change of `-100` with reason of `Serial voting was reversed`, then the system will have realised this has happened. Otherwise, you can flag one of the affected questions or answers with a `requires moderator attention` flag, and explain the reason to them, so the moderators can look at the votes and reset them if necessary.

The system should detect the votes at any time from 3am UTC onwards, so expect the fix to come in less than 24 hours (if it was a single user)

***EDIT:*** As you can now see on your profile, you have a `-90` reversal score, so your votes have been fixed.

Comment: In the OP's case, I don't think it will get reversed. I've had two serial voting reversals happen to me. Both reversions were ~140. At least the first one was, I believe, unfair*. During the first time, I noticed another user who fields similar Qs, also received ~120 points and **didn't** have their points reversed. So, unless threshold has changed, OP may be fine. *https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274430/316019

Comment: @Gyan it had been corrected already, two hours before you made your comment...

Comment: @Gyan The time when the votes were made may also matter. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375804/got-100-reputation-in-1-minute-should-i-be-worried?cb=1#comment641722_375804

Comment: It happened to me once.  I found that it was a single user upvoting many of my Answers, then suddenly all being reversed.  I assume he honestly liked my stuff, but I also understand the automated reversal.

Answer (score 11):

Many of the votes were automatically reversed. I've messaged the responsible party. It's not the first time they've done this with you. It seems you have a fan.

I've also contacted the community team to look at the votes.

If it continues the person in question will receive a suspension. [The site doesn't tolerate targeted voting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed).

It's a good thing you bring it up. Raise a custom mod flag if you notice anything like this again.

Comment: By simple curiosity, is it OK to target-vote Community Wiki posts created by the same user?

Comment: @Cœur any user targeting doesn't fare well. It's how the system is designed.

Comment: @Cœur: it would be interesting to see if the +/-1 votes were reversed, but there would be no scores to reset. I wonder if this has ever happened?

Comment: @halfer that's a good point. How do CWs show up in a user's activity?

Comment: Cheers, yea I see a -90 now. It should go to -150 I think when done. I see more again recently.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty the best way to protect your account is to let us know - like this meta post, always feel free to flag it when it happens. You can include a link to this meta post.