# What can I do if I receive a persistent flood of revenge downvotes through multiple automatic reversals?

Tags: discussion, support, downvotes, serial-voting

After I got a serial downvote, the bot fixed (some of) the downvotes, and I thought all was well, but after 4 hours, a *second* serial downvote occurs, and the bot has yet to respond, I know I should wait, but I'm a bit sick and tired of this! All my answers to all my questions I've ever made except 1 are in the negatives! Half of my questions are in the negatives too!

I went from 160 rep to 129 rep and also got caught in the automatic question ban just because of this. This is what just some of it looks like:

[image: Serial Downvotes after Reversal]

Is there any action I can take to get this addressed properly and who should I contact with this? Even if the automated script gets rid of most of the downvotes each night, it looks like this will just continue.

Not a duplicate of: [What can I do about getting a sudden flood of revenge downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes)

I feel like people who do this should be punished or face some repercussions, It feels really bad they can just go and and spree-downvote me every day, and keep getting me temporarily question banned, only to keep doing it again the next day.

Comment: @DavyM This is a repeat revenge downvote, it has happened again after a reversal has already occured

Comment: And the next time the reversal script runs, it should catch it again :)

Comment: On the bright side, you can have a laugh at the sorry fool who is wasting time every day downvoting you just to have a computer undo everything they're doing...

Comment: Aside from the fact that this is a duplicate. A user who contributes to the site is peacefully going on and on in life, but someone does something bad and the other user has lose rep which is not an issue but they get a question ban. It gets undone after a day but still, someone’s action is affecting someone’s rights on SO which bothers me. The system which bans people from asking questions should check for serial downvotes and downvote history

Comment: Finally someone who agrees, I have permanent question bans now, and I think I have to get about 10-20 more upvotes just to remove it ;-; (REVERSALS DONT SEEM TO UNDO THE DAMAGE! IM STILL QUESTION BANNED EVEN AFTER REVERSALS!!)

Comment: I'm having a look at your account now.

Comment: I am contacting the team to get your ban lifted. The person who keeps downvoting you has been warned. Raise a mod flag if you receive more downvotes like this.

Comment: There is no such thing as a permanent question ban, because when you are question banned, you are allowed to ask another question in 6 months.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Warned? Hey, modding is your turf and you know how to do it better than I do, but this is egregious behavior, and in your shoes I would have given at least a week’s suspension.

Comment: @Yvette I thought moderators were not able to individually lift question bans? Our FAQ on the ban even says this. Has this changed?

Comment: @RobertColumbia I referred it to the community team. I'm not even sure if they can lift it.

Comment: @DanBron yes that's right modding is my turf and I have all the facts ;)

Comment: The title of this question should be "What can I do about getting a not-so-sudden extended flood of revenge downvotes that continues through multiple reversals?" The duplicate target here doesn't touch on that.

Comment: Hey @TaylorSpark I edited your question substantially to (as far as I can tell) bring out what you were asking about, removing some of the superflous parts and making it more distinguished and reopenable from the duplicate. Feel free to roll my edits back if they unfairly change the substance of your question... I also reopened the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you noted, revenge downvotes often get reversed by the automatic script, but that's not a tenable long term solution if someone just keeps doing it.

The best way to proceed in such a case is to alert the moderators about the issue. The easiest way to do this is to raise a custom flag on one of your posts, as "needs moderator attention". Be specific and detailed, and include the fact that the downvoting has persisted across multiple days and reversals now, but don't engage in speculation.

Moderators will then asess the situation and hand out warnings / punishments or escalate as necessary.

Persistent user-targeted voting is against the rules of stack overflow and will get the voters in trouble, up or down.

Comment: The main problem with this approach is that moderators cannot see who voted. They would need to escalate this to a SE employee. You might thus just as well write a detailed complaint in the 'contact' form from the start.

Comment: @Adriaan While mods can't see who voted, they have aggregate tooling for determining such abuse, and can escalate themselves as necessary. See yvette's comments

Comment: @Magisch luckily It seems that due to my writing of this question, the said person who was downvoting me has since stopped and Im now at a higher rep, and my question ban has actually been removed (thankfully)