# Serial Downvoting Reversal mechanism not working

Tags: support, voting

I downvoted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76298092/vs-and-rider-ignore-source-generator-generated-files?noredirect=1#comment134548173_76298092) and upvoted it in a flash of an eye. I thought about downvoting to undo the action, but then I left that job for the serial voting mechanism to do its job and reverse the action.

I followed the question, so I would notice if the system corrected the activity by reading the new reputation of the OP. It's now more than five hours since I did that and the upvote is still upheld, unless my understanding of what serial downvoting and upvoting is, is incorrect.

Comment: I  think that your understanding of what serial downvoting is and what it does may not be correct. It is supposed to correct and remove multiple downvotes cast by one site member on multiple questions made another site member.

Comment: What you describe isn’t serial upvoting. Besides the serial downvoting script only runs once a day. **It hasn’t ran today.** To be clear your vote cannot be reversed since it’s been more than 5 minutes and it’s not a candidate for serial upvoting.

Comment: Okay if that's the case then that explains what I observed then. My understanding is incorrect.

Comment: I though the script covered even accidental upvotes and downvotes made on a single question by the same user

Comment: @DongLi - That’s just the grace period for a vote. Your understanding isn’t accurate

Comment: What is the grace period of a vote and why isn't there a mechanism to prevent multiple votes on a single post by the same user

Comment: Clicking the same voting buttons multiple times is not what serial voting is. You can’t downvote or upvote any post more than once. The voting buttons are toggles. If you haven’t downvoted, you downvote by clicking it. If you click it agaim, your voting is undone.

Comment: @DongLi - I just said the grace period is 5 minutes, after 5 minutes the vote cannot be reversed, unless the contribution is edited. A user can only issue a single vote on a contribution, what you describe is a single vote, a single upvote after you reversed a downvote.

Comment: Serial voting refers to targeting a specific user with votes. As in, going to their profile page, and repeatedly voting on several of their questions and/or answers.

Comment: Your upvote also reverted your downvote. There was in effect just one vote by you.

Comment: Grace period: See e.g. *[Can we get rid of locked votes or have a longer grace period?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98673/can-we-get-rid-of-locked-votes-or-have-a-longer-grace-period)*. But there must be a FAQ entry somewhere.

Comment: There's no way for the system to know whether the user voted the post accidentally or [they lost their keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/241919).

Comment: Hello, "Passionate SE" alias "Publius Flavius Tiberius" alias "CodeTiger" alias "Dong Li"

Comment: @PeterMortensen, Name changing is a privilege granted to us by the site every thirty days. Now, you wouldn't happen to have any problem with that, would you?

Comment: In a vacuum, there's no problem (I've changed mine because my old one was dumb). But if you say... post a bunch of things, comment a lot, and change your name frequently, it may come across as an attempt to sidestep accountability and confuse discussion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each user gets only one vote per post. That vote can be *either* up *or* down.

So, if you upvote a post, then downvote that same post, the system **converts** (i.e., *changes*) your original upvote into a downvote on that post. The same would be true if you downvoted and then upvoted a post: the system would convert your original downvote into an upvote, leaving only an upvote from you on that post.

You can also *retract* your vote by attempting to redo the same type of vote that you originally cast. So, say you upvoted a post because it looked superficially good, but then you realized that it was generated by an AI, which is [not allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned). You could retract your upvote by clicking again on the upvote button. This would cause the system to remove your upvote. Remember that a user cannot vote on a post twice, so clicking the upvote button a second time doesn't cast a second upvote; it undoes the original. This is how you would retract a vote without *switching* your vote to the opposite type of vote.

There is one additional complication: in order to limit a relatively obscure abuse mechanism called "tactical voting", the system is currently designed to lock in your vote after a particular period of time (i.e., after a grace period). I won't get into what exactly tactical voting is here because it is not germane to understanding how the voting system works. The point is merely that you only have a certain grace period (currently set to 5 minutes) within which you are able to either undo (retract) or change your vote on a particular post. After that grace period expires, your vote is locked in, so you cannot change it. (If the post is edited by anyone, the lock-in no longer applies, and you can then change or remove your vote on that post.)

"Serial up/downvoting" is something else entirely. This is when one user goes through and casts a large number of votes on different posts in rapid succession. This is often done when targeting posts from a particular user, but it could also just be done indiscriminately. Basically, it's when you're thoughtlessly voting on posts without reading or evaluating them. There are system processes to automatically revert these types of votes, based on a variety of heuristics (which we do not disclose the details of in order to reduce the opportunity for folks to game the system). This system *does* work, but it is imperfect, so if it doesn't work for you, then you can raise a moderator flag on one of your posts (any one will do) to explain the issue and ask that the targeted votes be investigated and removed as appropriate. Note that the script that automatically reverts these only runs every 24 hours (generally at a particular time each UTC day), so you should wait a full 24 hours to give it the opportunity to work before raising a moderator flag. For more information on serial voting, see here: [What can I do about getting a sudden flood of revenge downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that if I upvoted then to undo the upvote I need to click on the same button. That's all I needed to learn. There is so much to learn on this site.

Comment: @DongLi there is much to learn... and there is a lot of information available. One is a solution to the other.

Comment: @Gimby, I didn't know that an edit needs to be at least six characters long until I made my first edit. I also didn't know that certain features are available to different users based on reputation count.